# how to call an interface method in the same class?

Tags: java, class, interface, actionlistener

I created an interface in a class. I want to call a method of this interface in the same class and just passing parameters to it

```java
public class NewArticle extends JFrame {
    interface NewArticleEvent{
        public void addarticle(String name ,String category,String B);        
    }
   .
   .
   .
    JButton add= new JButton("add");
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* I want to call 'addarticle' method here * /

        }
    });
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I want to call my method `addarticle` here using my 3 defined parameters:

- `l1.gettext().tostring()`
- `l2.gettext().tostring()`
- `l3.gettext().tostring()`

because I want to use this method with those parameters in another class.

Comment: If you have an instance that implements NewArticleEvent you can just call instance.addarticle().

Comment: Maybe you can make method `addarticle` a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in interface `NewArticleEvent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of NewArticleEvent in order to use it's methods.

A solution could be to pass to NewArticle class an object that implements NewArticleEvent and call the method where you need to. Further code would be appreciated.